# Multi Tenant SaaS Reference Application

Tags: rest, architecture, saas, multi-tenant

I want to build multi-tenant SaaS based Rest Application, is there any open source products or other reference implementations for best practices of implementing the above architecture.

I am planning to use Java Platform

Comment: why some body voted to close?

Answer (score 1):

There are different multi tenant strategies, like using one or multiple DB.

You should look at these different strategies, according to your needs, before we can really answer.

I like having a shared DB which is easier for maintenance.

You can easily do it with Hibernate filters. Here's an exemple using also Play framework:
http://www.lunatech-research.fr/archives/2011/03/04/play-framework-writing-multitenancy-application-hibernate-filters
You can probably shard on the tenant_id for scalability. There is Hibernate Shards (but not really active).

There are many ways to implement such a feature according to the strategy.
I think Groovy has a plugin to do it easily.